# rollapply na.rm = TRUE giving 0 values instead of NA's

Tags: r, na, rollapply, na.rm

I have a simple question, that I can't seem to find the answer to on google, stackoverflow or stackexchange.  I am currently working with the example of `rollapply` to find the sum of some values that contain NA's.  For example:

```
 z <- zoo(c(NA, NA, NA, NA,2, 3, 4, 5, NA))
 rollapply(z, 3, sum, na.rm = TRUE, align = "right")
```

This outputs:

```
  3  4  5  6  7  8  9 
  0  0  2  5  9 12  9
```

This looks good, however, there are two times where there are 3 NA's in a row.  The sum feature exchanges NA's to 0's.  Unfortunately, that won't work with the data I'm going to work with since 0 is a meaningful value.  Is there a way to replace the 0's with NA's again?

I'm looking for an output as below:

```
  3   4   5  6  7  8  9 
  NA  NA  2  5  9 12  9
```

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do the following (even though not very nice)

```
require(zoo)
z <- zoo(c(NA, NA, NA, NA,2, 3, 4, 5, NA))
tmp <- rollapply(z, 3, sum, na.rm = TRUE, align = "right")

tmp[is.na(z)[-2:-1] & tmp == 0] <- NA
tmp
```

so you assign `NA` wherever `z` is na and there is a `NA` produced by `rollapply`

which gives you:

```
> tmp
 3  4  5  6  7  8  9 
NA NA  2  5  9 12  9
```

Comment: `roll_sumr` still gives me the same result as `rollapply`.  I modified your code to `roll_sumr(z, 3, na.rm = TRUE)` but still gave me a similar result as before.  The output i'm looking for is stated in the main question.

Comment: "Not very nice", but hey it gets the job done.  Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Here are two approaches:

**1)** Note that it is not that `rollapply` is giving 0 but that `sum(x, na.rm = TRUE)` is giving 0.  The function `sum(x, na.rm = TRUE)` is not really what is desired here.

Instead, provide a version of `sum` that works in the way needed, i.e. it returns `NA` when the input is entirely `NA` values and returns `sum(x, na.rm = TRUE)` otherwise.

```
sum_na <- function(x) if (all(is.na(x))) NA else sum(x, na.rm = TRUE)
rollapplyr(z, 3, sum_na)
```

**2)** Alternately, use your code and fix it up afterwards by replacing any position that was all `NA` with an `NA`:

```
zz <- rollapplyr(z, 3, sum, na.rm = TRUE)
zz[rollapply(is.na(z), 3, all)] <- NA
```

giving:

```
> zz
 3  4  5  6  7  8  9 
NA NA  2  5  9 12  9
```